# Extracting URL from the address bar of a browser

Tags: url, browser, java

I have coded a java program to extract the content of a webpage of a hard coded URL. Now I want to extract an URL from a web browser as the user visits it, instead of using the hard coded URL. are there any java libraries or APIs to do this ?

Comment: [**`document.location`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location) or **`request.getRequestURL()`** ??

Comment: Your question is about java or javascript?

Comment: I want to get the URL not the location. The question is about java

Answer (score 0):

A HTML document has several patterns and different tags. Extracting an useful information (the relevant content) isn't easy, because you should to understand how the page is written to really know what part of the content is relevant or not.

There's a general propose to extract only relevant content from a web page called [biolerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/), wich one was published in the ACM. It uses some heuristics to find relevant pieces of text and extract them.

If you want to extract an URL from a document you need to search for the  and extract the URL or, if the URL isn't in a  tag, you need to seek inside the page content for an url pattern to extract the link properly. There's no other option to get URLs from pages (documents).

You can't avoid the HTML tags and scripts presented in the URL content (in the form that the browser shows for you), because those tags are part of the URL content. To get the relevant content of an URL, you can use the boilerpipe to extract the useful information (which uses the URL class). Otherwise, you can use the URL class.

Once you have boilerpipe on your classpath, extracting the "main" content from a Web page is really simple:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");
// NOTE: Use ArticleExtractor unless DefaultExtractor gives better results for you
String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

But there are some pages that Boilerpipe can't extract, that I fixed [here](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/issues/detail?id=70). I attached the source code with the fix. This fix avoid the following exception `"HTTP response code : 403 for URL"`in some pages.

Comment: I don't want to get the URL of a given page. I want to get the URL of any webpage when the user visits it. Is there any method to use javascript in java code to do this ???